# C# MVC - Controller not receiving all data from ViewModel form

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm new working with c# MVC and this is my first project/test.

I'm making a simple MVC project using C# MVC. My problem is that when I submit my form from the view the controller is receiving part of the data, and if I do the same post from PostMan the controller receives all of it.

Here is my code:

View:

```
<form asp-action="NewTask" asp-controller="Task" class="form-horizontal" name="NewTask">
<div class="table">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            Title:
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input class="form-control" name="Title" id="Title" type="text" placeholder="Title" />
        </dd>
        <dt>
            Description:
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input class="form-control" name="Description" id="Description" type="text" placeholder="Description" />
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <input type="hidden" name="Status" id="Status" value="A" />
        </dd>
        <dt>
            User:
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(task => task.User, new SelectList(ViewBag.Users, "Id", "Username"), "Please Select One...", new { @class = "form-control", @name = "User"})                                
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" />
</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CreateTaskViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult NewTask([FromBody] CreateTaskViewModel TaskVM)
    {
        var item = new Models.Task
        {
            Title = TaskVM.Title,
            Description = TaskVM.Description,
            Status = TaskVM.Status
        };

        var users = _userRepository.Find(Convert.ToInt32(TaskVM.User));

        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _taskRepository.NewTask(item);

        var userTask = new UserTask
        {
            Status = "A",
            UserId = users.Id,
            TaskId = item.Id
        };
        _userTaskRepository.NewUserTask(userTask);
        return View("Tasks");
    }
```

I added a breakpoint on the `var item = new Models.Task` line when I submit the form and the TaskVM object have all the values of the fields Title, Description and Status but the User value comes null.

If I capture the request in the browser's Inspect option and send it from Postman it works perfectly.

What do I need to change in my view or controller?

EDIT:
This is the generated HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="NewTask" action="/Task" method="post">
<div class="table">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            Title:
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input class="form-control" name="Title" id="Title" type="text" placeholder="Title" />
        </dd>
        <dt>
            Description:
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input class="form-control" name="Description" id="Description" type="text" placeholder="Description" />
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <input type="hidden" name="Status" id="Status" value="A" />
        </dd>
        <dt>
            User:
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The User field is required." id="User" name="User"><option value="">Please Select One...</option>
                <option value="1">User 1</option>
                <option value="2">User 2</option>
                <option value="3">User 3</option>
                <option value="">etc...</option>
            </select>                                
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" />
</div>
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="dQhqzqtPv5jtvF4dmgleh4HqwmIa6w9ancJdYGLWKKWmnnkZS-IjSh9NFSUDeSPsfr9vNHiro1i4a4" />
```

Comment: Please post the generated HTML as well as the definition of the  type that populates `ViewBag.Users`.

Comment: @JuanR I eddited the the question and posted the generated HTML. The ViewBag.Users returns a list of Users (Id, Username)

Comment: Thank you. Can you post the class for user itself? I am curious about the properties.

Comment: @JuanR `public int Id { get; set; }` and `public string Username { get; set; }`

Comment: What's the name of the class???

Comment: @JuanR `public class Users`

Comment: When inspecting the browser request, do you see a value for user? Can you post what you see there?

Comment: @JuanR yes! The browser captures the value for User.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169269/discussion-between-juanr-and-magdielaybar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used JSon/JQuery to post the form to my controller.

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    submitForm();
});

function submitForm() {
    Task = new Object();
    Task.Title = $("#Title").val();
    Task.Description = $("#Description").val();
    Task.Status = $("#Status").val();
    Task.UserId = $("#UserId").find(":selected").val();
    newTask(Task);
}

function newTask(Task) {
    var s = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Task))
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://url:port/Task",
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        datatype: 'json',            
        data: JSON.stringify(s),
        success: function (data) {
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function (request, message, error) {
            location.reload();               
        }
    });
}
```